# Beating the state machine

Tags: opengl

I'm working on a plugin for a scripting language that allows the user to access the OpenGL 1.1 command set. On top of that, all functions of the scripting language's own gfx command set are transparently redirected to appropriate OpenGL calls. Normally, the user should use *either* the OpenGL command set *or* the scripting language's inbuilt gfx command set which basically contains just your typical 2D drawing commands like `DrawLine()`, `DrawRectangle()`, `DrawPolygon()`, etc.

Under certain conditions, however, the user might want to mix calls to the OpenGL *and* the inbuilt gfx command sets. This leads to the problem that my OpenGL implementations of inbuilt commands like `DrawLine()`, `DrawRectangle()`, `DrawPolygon()`, etc. have to be able to deal with whatever state the OpenGL state machine might currently be in.

Therefore, my idea was to first save *all* state information on the stack, then prepare a clean OpenGL context needed for my implementations of commands like `DrawLine()`, etc. and then restore the original state. E.g. something like this:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glPushMatrix();
....prepare OpenGL context for my needs.... --> problem: see below #2
....do drawing....
glPopMatrix();
glPopClientAttrib();
glPopAttrib();
```

Doing it like this, however, leads to several problems:

1. `glPushAttrib()` doesn't push all attributes, e.g save pixel pack and unpack state, render mode state, and select and feedback state are not pushed. Also, extension states are not saved. Extension states are not important as my plugin is not designed to support extensions. Saving and restoring other information (pixel pack and unpack) could probably be implemented manually using `glGet()`.
2. Big problem: How should I prepare the OpenGL context after having saved all state information? I could save a copy of a "clean" state on the stack right after OpenGL's initialization and then try to pop this stack but for this I'd need a function to move data inside the stack, i.e. I'd need a function to copy or move a saved state from the back to the top of stack so that I can pop it. But I didn't see a function that can accomplish this...
3. It's probably going to be very slow but this is something I could live with because the user *should not* mix OpenGL and inbuilt gfx calls. If he does nevertheless, he will have to live with a very poor performance.

After these introductory considerations I'd finally like to present my question: Is it possible to "beat" the OpenGL state machine somehow? By "beating" I mean the following: Is it possible to completely save all current state information, then restore the default state and prepare it for my needs and do the drawing, and then finally restore the complete previous state again so that everything is exactly as it was before. For example, an OpenGL based version of the scripting language's DrawLine() command would do something like this then:

```
1. Save all current state information
2. Restore default state, set up a 2D projection matrix
3. Draw the line
4. Restore all saved state information so that the state is exactly the same as before
```

Is that possible somehow? It doesn't matter if it's very slow as long as it is 100% guaranteed to put the state into exactly the same state as it was before.

Comment: By the way: `glPushAttrib (...)` only pushes server-state, pixel store state is client-state. There is a separate function, `glPushClientAttrib (...)` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use different contexts, especially if you do not care about performance. Just keep an context for your internal gfx operations and another one the user might mess with and just bind the appropriate one to your window (and thread).

The way you describe it looks like you never want to share objects with the user's GL stuff, so simple "unshared" contexts will do fine. All you seem to want to share is the framebuffer -  and the GL framebuffer (including back and front color buffers, depth buffer, stencil, etc..) is part of the drawable/window, not the context - so you get access to it whit any context when you make the context current. Changing the contexts mid-frame is not a problem.

Comment: This might be a suitable workaround, but I'm struggling to find out how to setup something like this. I'm using GLFW and contexts seem to be automatically tied to the window. How do I have to create these two contexts and make them share the same GL framebuffer?

Comment: @Andreas: Context are just tied to any window in particular. You can always attach a different context to a window, do your thing with it, and then restore. Since GLFW offers no context API you'll have to hack around it (or you modify GLFW accordingly, it's open source after all). If you want to hack around it, at initialization create your secondary context. Use `wglGetCurrentDC` (Windows) or `glXGetCurrentDrawable` to retrieve a handle to the window's DC. Then use the usual methods for context creation.

Comment: @Andreas: With `{wgl,glX}GetCurrentContext` you get the active context before you bind the other context and with `{wgl,glX}MakeCurrent` you bind and restore your own, and the previously active context. Before unbinding a context call `glFlush`.

Comment: @Andreas: Unfortunately, GLFW's windows and context abstraction is not flexible enough to do this for you -  and I always disliked the "window+context" strategy since it abstracts away a lot of the underlying functionality and flexibility. So datenwolf's suggestions are the way to go if you want to follow the "multiple contexts" strategy. Extending GLFW would be the ideal way - it shouldn't be that hard after all, since all the stuff to deal with the various GL interface  APIs is already there, just the external API needs to be extended.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to hack this into GLFW and see if it works the way I want. Still it would be interesting to know if one could really beat the state machine without working around it :)